# Highcharts How to add a link in PlotLines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was working with Highcharts using PlotLines. I would like to add a link to do something (delete or update for example) inside the label of the PlotLine.

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Add Link in PlotLines'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia'],
                },
                yAxis: {
                    plotLines:[{
                        value:450,
                        color: '#ff0000',
                        width:2,
                        zIndex:4,
                        id:'PlotLine1',
                        label:{text:'PlotLine 1 ' + '<a href="#" onClick="delete(PlotLine1);">Delete</a>'}               
                    },
                     {
                        value:200,
                        color: '#000055',
                        width:2,
                        id:'PlotLine2', 
                        zIndex:4,
                        label:{text:'PlotLine 2 ' + '<a href="#" onClick="delete(PlotLine2);">Delete</a>'}                
                    }]                
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Year 1800',
                    data: [107, 31, 50]
                },
                        {
                    name: 'Goal',
                            type: 'scatter',
                            marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    data: [450]
                }]
            });
        });


});
```

If you see the source code generated of the PlotLines you can see something like this:

```
<tspan onclick="location.href="#"" style="cursor: pointer;" dx="3">
      Delete
</tspan>
```

I don't know if there is any way to add a link or a button into the label.
The source is in http://jsfiddle.net/nDjdc/21/

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't seem carry the `onClick` attribute when it renders, but it does carry the `href` so you can do this:

```
<a href="javascript: deleteMe('PlotLine1');">Delete</a>
```

I created a working fiddle off yours. Please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/V82pQ/

Only caveat is that it only has access to global objects, so I hope you namespace your application appropriately :)

Fyi `delete` is not a good name for variable because it's a reserved word. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words